# Shortcut to Chrome's native screenshot tool?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

Is there an quicker way to utilize Chrome's native screenshot tool than to `Right-click Inspect > Toggle Device Toolbar > Three Dot Menu > Capture screenshot` ?

I am not looking for an extension. Its pretty onerous to have to go through so many steps to take advantage of a simple and widely used capability. Firefox has [their own version](https://screenshots.firefox.com/) that is more easily accessible by having it in the right-click context menu.

Comment: I think you need an extension for that. Are you ok with that?

Comment: "I am not looking for an extension."

Comment: In that case your only solution is to install a macro-program that will do the clicking for you. Might not an extension be simpler?

Comment: You could at least open the device toolbar instantly by pressing  CTRL + SHIFT + I
but you would still have to press the menubutton and Capture Screenshot after that.